# Converting microseconds (?) to date and time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I had:

```
index| raw_data
150 1535932800000000
151 1506902400000000
152 1506902400000000
153 1506902400000000
154 1506902400000000
155 1506902400000000
```

I performed this code:

```
#seconds
df_csv['document_date'] = df_csv['document_date'].floordiv(1000000)
#date and time
df_csv['document_date'] = df_csv['document_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Result:

```
index| transformed_data
150 2018-09-03 00:00:00
151 2017-10-02 00:00:00
152 2017-10-02 00:00:00
153 2017-10-02 00:00:00
154 2017-10-02 00:00:00
155 2017-10-02 00:00:00
```

I used, the source:

https://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=0&timestamp=1535932800&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++

and at least line 150 and 151 are not returning the hours correctly, can someone understand how/why? In case of missing some info, please, just ask. Thanks :)

Comment: *line 150 and 151 are not returning the hours correctly,* What do you expect?

Comment: hey @QuangHoang consulting the site attached, u'll see:  9/3/2018, 1:00:00 (and not 00:00:00), also the same for line 151, with other date :)

Comment: Depending on the different timezones. I got different time from your link: `9/2/2018, 8:00:00 PM`. You may want to specify it as well.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Are you using `read_csv()` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for the insight, gonna try it :)

Comment: @AMC, yes, using read_csv() :)

Comment: the output of the linked site is slightly confusing, be careful. e.g. for me, it is assuming I'm on CET summer time / UTC+2 => CET is correct but UTC+2 is wrong at the moment since DST is still winter time, so UTC+1. Long story short, I think Python/Pandas is doing it right. Also, use `pd.to_datetime` with `utc=True, unit='us'` instead of `apply` to make your code cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: @MrFuppes, thank you very much for ur time, pd.to_datetime is awesome!        150 2018-09-03 00:00:00+00:00, I still got the same result, so I'm gonna believe pandas is doing the right thing :P

Answer (score 0):

so, following @MrFuppes recommendation:

```
   df_csv['document_date']=  pd.to_datetime(df_csv['document_date'], utc=True, unit='us')
```

and got:

```
    150 2018-09-03 00:00:00+00:00
    151 2017-10-02 00:00:00+00:00
    152 2017-10-02 00:00:00+00:00
    153 2017-10-02 00:00:00+00:00
    154 2017-10-02 00:00:00+00:00
    155 2017-10-02 00:00:00+00:00
```

hope is helpful :)